# Login-Authentication to a remote mysql database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have this line of code here.

My java code:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
         $public void onClick(View v) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", txtUsername.getText().toString()));  
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", txtPassword.getText().toString())); 




    //String valid = "1";  
    String response = null;  
    try {  
    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://www.sampleweb.com/imba.php", postParameters);  
    String res=response.toString();  
    // res = res.trim();  
    res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");  
    //error.setText(res);  
    if(res.equals("1")){
    txtError.setText("Correct Username or Password"); 
    //Intent i = new Intent(CDroidMonitoringActivity.this, MenuClass.class);
    //startActivity(i);
    }
    else {
    txtError.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");  
    } 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
    txtUsername.setText(e.toString());  

    }

}
                });
            }
```

My php script code:

```
   <?php
     $un=$_POST['username'];
     $pw=$_POST['password'];

     $user = ‘bduser’;
     $pswd = ‘dbpwd’;
     $db = ‘phplogin’;
     $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$un' AND password = '$pw'");
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());

      if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)

     echo 1; // for correct login response
     else
     echo 0; // for incorrect login response
      ?>
```

I have a problem with this code. In my android code when I try to change the res.equals to contains. It always say correct password but if I will not change it, it says incorrect password. I don't know there is something wrong in my java code or in my php code. really need help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is in the PHP code.

Change the following line:-

**From:**

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$un' AND password = '$pw'");
```

**To:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$un' AND password = '$pw'";
```

You should also consider making changes to prevent SQL Injection:-

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = 
    WHERE username='%s' AND password='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($un),
    mysql_real_escape_string($pw));
```

Comment: sir what's the purpose of that SQL injection?

Comment: Given the fact you're receiving data from request, you should sanitize it to avoid receiving data formatted in a way that can allow "bad guys" to login and even access to your data and databse structures. Look out for SQL injection and read some about it.

Comment: Im sorry. Its been my first time to encounter that Sql injection. Im new with php.

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP to 'select count(*)' and check for the actual numeric value of the result. This way you aren't trying to compare against a possible NULL which can throw off line counts.

Also check your PHP separately to make sure you're getting the correct response from the ECHO.

Be aware that your android code will block until it gets a result. You should probably recode it in a thread. Otherwise the device will throw 'non responsive' and exit if SQL is too slow.

EDIT: add some code - slightly different in that it checks for whether or not a specific value is set rather than whether anything was returned. Same idea, a few more lines of code.

```
/** Authenticate a login.
 *
 * @param string $Username
 * @param string $Password
 * @return int
 */
function login( $Username, $Password )
{
    Logger::DEBUG( "Login attempt by '" . $Username . "'");

    try
    {
        $conn = DBConnection::_getConsole2DB();

        $query = "select LoginId, UserId, RoleId, ProjectMask, RestrictionMask from Users where LoginId = ? and Password = ? and Active = 1";
        $st = $conn->prepare( $query );
        $st->bindParam( 1, $Username );
        $st->bindParam( 2, $Password );
        $st->execute();

        $row = $st->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
                    if( !isset( $row[ 'UserId' ])) return 0;

        $this->userId = $row[ 'UserId' ];
        $this->roleId = $row[ 'RoleId' ];
        $this->projectMask = $row[ 'ProjectMask' ];
        $this->restrictionMask = $row[ 'RestrictionMask' ];         

        $_SESSION[ 'userId' ] = $this->userId;
        $_SESSION[ 'roleId' ] = $this->roleId;
        $_SESSION[ 'projectMask' ] = $this->projectMask;
        $_SESSION[ 'restrictionMask' ] = $this->restrictionMask;
        $_SESSION[ 'loginId' ] = $row[ 'LoginId' ];

    }
    catch( PDOException $e )
    {
        Logger::PDO_ERROR( $e );
        return -1; // error
    }

    return 1; 
}
```

This uses PDO so there are some small syntax differences with what you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are doing mysql_query(mysql_query()) I believe.

First try:

```
txtError.setText(res);
```

By the way: SQL injection. If you enter as password:

```
' UNION SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='admin
```

Comment: I have tried to put the res in the open and close parenthesis. But it have provide an error from mysql.