# Java query to website user database

Tags: java, php

I am trying to figure out the method on connecting a java program to my website. I have a program that allows users to download jars to run as scripts in this program. For some of the jars, I want them to have a login that queries my website. So a user tries to run the script and has to enter details that correspond with their wordpress username on my website, and a certain DB field must be true to continue.

I don't have high encryption on these jars, so I'd prefer the username and password be merely sent to a php file to do the processing on my secure server. So I guess this is more of a PHP question in the end.

Anyway, I hope I'm clear on what I want.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185905/login-authentication-to-a-remote-mysql-database

Comment: The library he's using is kind of confusing to install @shapeshifter. Basically I'm struggling with the java now. I'm using Wordpress login and here is my PHP:

      <?php
     $un=$_POST['username'];
     $pw=$_POST['password'];

    $creds = array();
  $creds['user_login'] = $un;
  $creds['user_password'] = $pw;
  $creds['remember'] = false;
  
  $user_verify = wp_signon ($creds, false );

  if(is_wp_error($user_verify))
   echo 0;
  else
   echo 1;
  
 ?>